# Gnuplot pngcairo and postscript terminals not rendering some special characters?

Tags: unicode, gnuplot, postscript, eps

I'm having trouble with the rendering of some characters in the pngcairo and postscript eps (both enhanced) terminals. The characters in question are the simple pipe, `|`, and the less/greater than characters, `<>`. These render in a completely broken way, with different characters altogether. To be specific, the following line:

```
set ylabel "<|S_{dy}(t)-S_{mc}(t)|/{/Symbol s}_{mc}(t)>"
```

produces the following result:

[image: Broken ylabel]

So, yes, basically it replaces the character with other random ones. Am I doing something wrong? Can this be fixed? This is gnuplot 5.2.2 I'm working with.

Comment: what is your operation system? what do you get if you type `show encoding`?

Comment: You're going to need to post an example file. I can look at EPS and PostScript files but I very much doubt that your problem relates to those. Most likely the font you are using doesn't include glyphs for the characters you want or, as theozh implies, the encoding applied to the font doesn't map the character codes to the correct glyphs in the font.

Comment: I managed to solve this by resorting to other fonts - though the font was cmr10 and I'm sure it should have those glyphs, maybe just different codes for them. Anyway I'll post my own answer under this.

Comment: glad you could solve it. However, to avoid guessing, please always provide enough information from the beginning, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up solving this by resorting to using different fonts. In particular, for the `<>` I actually went with two slightly different glyphs that better suited my needs from Symbol, and for the `|` I used Times New Roman. The final line looked like:

```
set ylabel "{/Symbol \341}{/TimesNewRoman \174}S_{dy}(t)-S_{mc}(t){/TimesNewRoman \174}/{/Symbol s}_{mc}(t){/Symbol \361}"
```

and rendered correctly.